# Obj-C: Why can the class name only be used as a message receiver or static type?

Tags: objective-c

It would be convenient to be able to specify a class object by its name rather than sending the `class` message to it. The runtime already knows what the `id` of the class is so why should I go through the trouble of sending a message each time to retrieve this?

My guess is that the compiler will optimize it so that this doesn't actually cause a message to be sent.

There must be some good reason (which I seek) that explains why the syntax must be this way.

Comment: I'm not which exact syntax you're referring to, could you add an example of what you mean?

Comment: Its because when you say something like `[NSObject doSomething]` or `[NSObject class]`, the `NSObject` is actually an instance of object type `Class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how it's designed to work: the class name is a type. Objects are pointers to that type. And a tpye alone can't be used as a value (constant, variable, expression, whatever you want to use it as...). If it's inconvenient for you (euh, it sholdn't be!), you can come up with a few workarounds: for eample, define a short macro:

```
#define C(name) [name class]
```

or

```
#define C(name) objc_getClass(#name)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think another way to phrase my question is what prevents the system from recognizing it and simply giving the `id` (which is the result of `[ClassName class]`) when I just write `ClassName`?

Comment: Because it's a type name, and not a value.

Comment: `static const Class CNSString = [NSString class];` is not valid objective-c classes (and messages) are not compile time constants.

Comment: It goes back to the impossibility of referring to a type as an value in C. However, I'm thinking of a blog post I recently saw about the various namespaces in C/Objective-C (e.g. structure tags vs. types vs. static values vs. auto values) which may contradict what I'm saying; I'll try to find it on Monday.

Comment: This doesn't explain at all why a class name can be used as the reciever of a message.